# Accessing one model from within another in Django many-to-one using ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, many-to-one

Lets imagine we have two models (many-to-one model).
Code below shows that a reporter can have multiple articles

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

Let's see what I have in my database on this model.

```
# Reporter.objects.all().values()
# <QuerySet [
# {'id': 1, 'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'email': 'john@example.com'},
# {'id': 2, 'first_name': 'Paul', 'last_name': 'Jones', 'email': 'paul@example.com'}
# ]>
# Article.objects.all().values()
# <QuerySet [
# {'id': 5, 'headline': "1st headline", 'pub_date': datetime.date(2005, 7, 29), 
# 'reporter_id': 1},
# {'id': 6, 'headline': "2nd headline", 'pub_date': datetime.date(2006, 1, 17), 
# 'reporter_id': 2},
# {'id': 7, 'headline': '3rd headline', 'pub_date': datetime.date(2005, 7, 27), 
# 'reporter_id': 1}
# ]>
```

The first reporter has two publications and second has the only.
I need to get the list of all articles for each reporter.
I tried this way (according to django docs):

```
Article.objects.filter(reporter__first_name='John')
```

It's okay. It works. I also tried to instantiate the first reporter as 'r1' and then do this:

```
r1.article_set.all()
```

And this piece of code works too.
But as I'm new to django, I think that instantiating the first reporter as 'r1' and then making a query is a bit slow. It is because django makes me run r1.save() and then r1.article_set.all(). It looks like django makes 2 query into database (first query - to save an instance, the second query to run r1.article_set.all)

Is my point of view correct? And how to query all the reporter's articles as fast as Article.objects.filter(reporter__first_name='John') but using the Reporter object?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried to instantiate the first reporter as 'r1' and then do this:
>
> ```
> r1.article_set.all()
> ```
>
> And this piece of code works too. But as I'm new to django, I think that instantiating the first reporter as 'r1' and then making a query is a bit slow.

**Yes**, but Django can load the related articles all with a second query in *bulk*. We do this with [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
reporters = Reporter.objects.prefetch_related('article_set')

for reporter in reporters:
    print(reporter.first_name)
    print(reporter.article_set.all())
```

Instead of the *N+1* queries that your implementations make (one query to fetch all reporters, and one query *per* reporter to fetch the related articles), this will make *two* queries: one to fetch all the reporters, and one to fetch all the articles related to one of these reporters. Django will then do some *joining* such that the articles related to the first reporter `r1` end up in `r1.article_set.all()`